# Individual width for li in PHP ul -for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

I'm creating a Wordpress template and need some advice. I'm using PHP inline
`ul` to display post results from different categories in a home page.

That works for me when I want all the posts displayed on the same size. However, I want some of the lines (categories) to include posts in different width. This is the code I use:

```
<ul class="posts">
<?php query_posts('category_name="category1"&showposts=4'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                <div class="post-thumb">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
                    <h4 class="post-title"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a> </h4>
                    <?php the_excerpt();?> 
       </div>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

This one returns 4 inline results for `Category1`, all with the same width. Any suggestions on how to edit each result's width individually?

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="col-md-3">` tells me this theme is based on [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). It divides the page into [twelve equal columns](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Try changing the class to `col-md-6` and it will take up half the page. Change it to `col-md-4` and it will take up a third, etc.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your reply! Indeed, I am using Bootstrap. I believe, however, that if I change the class as you suggest, those changes will apply on all results. Do you have any suggestions on how the individual width of each result can be affected? Thank you for your time!

Comment: An `if` statement, I would imagine.